# Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token character '/' in token "multipart/form-data"

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

I have the following test case. When I run it I get the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token character '/' in token "multipart/form-data"".

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/xyz.dat");
    File f = new File(url.getFile());
    FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream(f);
    MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "linga", "multipart/form-data", f1);
    MediaType mediaType = new MediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/someurl")
            .content(mockMultipartFile.getBytes())
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token character '/' in token "multipart/form-data"
at org.springframework.util.MimeType.checkToken(MimeType.java:182)
at org.springframework.util.MimeType.<init>(MimeType.java:153)
at org.springframework.util.MimeType.<init>(MimeType.java:118)
at org.springframework.util.MimeType.<init>(MimeType.java:107)
at org.springframework.http.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:220)
at com.tangomc.kettle.oven.controllers.FileBoxControllerTest.testUploadFile(FileBoxControllerTest.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Jul 07, 2015 6:29:13 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 31 ms
```

I got it while running the above test case on a controller that uploads files.

UPDATE: I get the error on this line:

```
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
```

Comment: Where do you get that *exception*?

Comment: stacktrace of exception?? have you tried `URL url = getClass().getResource("xyz.dat");`??

Comment: Post the full stacktrace please.

Comment: the file is one part in a multipart. the request body needs to be a multipart (which may encapsulate just one part).

Comment: What is your post method return? `MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder` or `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`?

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong [constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#MediaType-java.lang.String-). this constructor takes only type as arguments and treats subtype as `*`

to fix your code change:

```
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
```

to:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
```

or:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA;
```